# HTML Links are not clickable, seem overlayed

Tags: html, css

I have a quite simple website. It scans for pictures via php and then displays them one at a time with two buttons on top. The bottons are used to switch back and forth between them.
On the very top of the page there are a couple of links, but I can not click them. When I double klick them, the picture gets highlighted instead of the text my cursor is above. I have tried it without js and php and the issue is still there.

I am not very experienced in HTML. I think it might be something about the z-index, but I cannot fix it.

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFFf
}

.menup1 {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 5.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 35px;
  background: #fffff;
  color: black;
}

a {
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

p {
  color: black;
}

.listelemt {}

ul {
  float: left;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

ul li {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 200px;
}

.container .btnF {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(600%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.container .btnB {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-675%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(105%, -50%);
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menup1"><a href="google.com">Vorspeise</a></div>
<div class="menup1"><a href="../../../Suppen">Suppen</a></div>
<div class="menup1"><a href="../../../Dessert">Dessert</a></div>
<div class="menup1"><a href="../../../Kuchen">Kuchen</a></div>
<div class="menup1"><a href="../../../Hauptgänge">Hauptgänge</a></div>
<div class="menup1"><a href="../../../Konditorei">Konditorei</a></div>
<div class="container">
  <img id="rezept" src="1.jpg" height=auto width=100%/>
  <button class="btnF" id="btnF">+</button>
  <button class="btnB" id="btnB">-</button>
</div>
```

I hope you can help me out here. I could manage to work out all the js and php things involved, but languages that don't follow programming rules... Not my best part.

Comment: What happens if you switch the order of the `container` and `menup1`s?

Comment: Why do you have an empty rule `.listelemt {}`?

Comment: CSS has rules... there are also conventions and good practices.  Replace those floats with inline blocks, wrap the links in a single nav element instead of individual divs, and the position absolute probably becomes unnecessary... also, use relative sizing (em or rem) rather than absolute pixels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't with `z-index`, but rather that your container is overlapping your menu items. To correct this, replace `padding-top: 200px` with `margin-top: 200px`, and give the container `float: left`. Alternatively, if you don't want to add any 'offset' with your container, you can clear the float before initialising it with `clear: left` on the container.

Also note that both your `body` and `.menup1` have invalid background-colours; when specifying hex codes, you *must* either specify three, four or six letters/digits. Five is invalid.

Both of these have been fixed in the following:

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.menup1 {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 5.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 35px;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: black;
}

a {
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

p {
  color: black;
}

.listelemt {}

ul {
  float: left;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

ul li {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.container .btnF {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(600%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.container .btnB {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-675%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(105%, -50%);
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menup1"><a href="google.com">Vorspeise</a></div>
<div class="menup1"><a href="../../../Suppen">Suppen</a></div>
<div class="menup1"><a href="../../../Dessert">Dessert</a></div>
<div class="menup1"><a href="../../../Kuchen">Kuchen</a></div>
<div class="menup1"><a href="../../../Hauptgänge">Hauptgänge</a></div>
<div class="menup1"><a href="../../../Konditorei">Konditorei</a></div>
<div class="container">
  <img id="rezept" src="1.jpg" height=auto width=100%/>
  <button class="btnF" id="btnF">+</button>
  <button class="btnB" id="btnB">-</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The z-index does cause an issue, or at least the `position: relative` does cause the stacking issue and can be "fixed" by altering the z-index.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you have the box over the links is the floats aren't being cleared. That means the box that contains the links collapses, which is probably why you need to add so much padding. If you add `clear: both` to the container you will be able to click the links.

If you want to keep everything else the same I suggest adding a wrapper around the menu and setting `position: relative`, then you can give that a `z-index` greater than the container.

The menu buttons which are both `position: absolute` then need higher `z-index` too.

```css
.menu {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.menup1 {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 5.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 35px;
  background: #fffff;
  color: black;
}

a {
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

p {
  color: black;
}

.listelemt {}

ul {
  float: left;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

ul li {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 200px;
}

.container .btnF {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(600%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.container .btnB {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-675%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(105%, -50%);
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menup1"><a href="google.com">Vorspeise</a></div>
    <div class="menup1"><a href="../../../Suppen">Suppen</a></div>
    <div class="menup1"><a href="../../../Dessert">Dessert</a></div>
    <div class="menup1"><a href="../../../Kuchen">Kuchen</a></div>
    <div class="menup1"><a href="../../../Hauptgänge">Hauptgänge</a></div>
    <div class="menup1"><a href="../../../Konditorei">Konditorei</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img id="rezept" src="1.jpg" height=auto width=100%/>
    <button class="btnF" id="btnF">+</button>
    <button class="btnB" id="btnB">-</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Okay, the links are clickable now, but the buttons are not clickable anymore.

Comment: It was getting late last night, here is a solution with correctly stacking `z-index`